# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. | RabbitMQ | .NET

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq

After reinstall windows 10 I have a problem.

[image]

I didn't change my code and befor reinstall windows it worked good.
I turn off firewall because I read that it can make the issue. But it didn't help me. How I can fix it?

Comment: This just means the machine you're connecting to refused to connect.

Comment: I see it. How I can fix it?

Comment: If you own the server, try modifying the .htaccess to allow access to all.

Comment: Can please to write ho to do it. In my app I don`t have .htaccess fie